# Complex Queries in Cassandra

Tags: cassandra

How can I make complex queries in Cassandra?

As example, I have a set of objects with id, name and others properties, and I want all Ids with the name starting with some string.

Is that possible?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

yes, thats plausible. use range queries and order preserving partitioner. (read [bens excellent slides](http://www.slideshare.net/benjaminblack/cassandra-basics-indexing) about index and range queries)

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, order preserving partition is not the ideal solution. What if you want to do range query base on some column value. Moreover,  partitioning scheme selected applies to a whole Cassandra instance, and not individual keyspace.

You have to roll out your own index. Check my post on this topic

http://pkghosh.wordpress.com/2011/03/02/cassandra-secondary-index-patterns/

Pranab